# How to identify multiple names used in google maps to key to the same name?

Tags: google-maps

Typically, a place name (e.g. Mumbai) has different names that show up in Google maps - e.g. Mumbai Maharashtra, Mumbai India or just Mumbai.

how do we identify it's the same place (without depending on co-ordinates which are known to change)? Something like a unique key or string name that I can use to look up into my application?

Answer (score 1):

This key exists. It is name the Place IDs. A place Id is unique for each address in the world. You can convert an address to a place id with this function:

```
var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: '500',
    query: 'Google Sydney'
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);


// Checks that the PlacesServiceStatus is OK, and adds a marker
// using the place ID and location from the PlacesService.
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log (results[0].place_id);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      place: {
        placeId: results[0].place_id,
        location: results[0].geometry.location
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is an other example maybe a quite more complicated:

```js
      // This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
      // for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
      // the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
      // selected.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }

          // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
          marker.setPlace({
            placeId: place.place_id,
            location: place.geometry.location
          });
          marker.setVisible(true);

          document.getElementById('place-name').textContent = place.name;
          document.getElementById('place-id').textContent = place.place_id;
          document.getElementById('place-address').textContent =
              place.formatted_address;
          infowindow.setContent(document.getElementById('infowindow-content'));
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .controls {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 29px;
        margin-left: 17px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        outline: none;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      .controls:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
      .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }
      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }
```

```html
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>

    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

---

This is another example of reverse geocoding with place id:

```js
// Initialize the map.
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.72, lng: -73.96}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      // This function is called when the user clicks the UI button requesting
      // a reverse geocode.
      function geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var placeId = document.getElementById('place-id').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'placeId': placeId}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        width: 440px;
      }
      #place-id {
        width: 250px;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <!-- Supply a default place ID for a place in Brooklyn, New York. -->
      <input id="place-id" type="text" value="ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode by Place ID">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

---

All this is a bit complicated...

You can consult the google developer web site for more informations:

- [Geocoding place id](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id?hl=en)
- [Example geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)
- [Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#place-id)
- [Example reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id?hl=en)

*Tell me if you do not understand or if you have some questions or some comments.*

Comment: You are a champ! Thanks! Will try this.

Comment: And I did try. And it works just fine. Thanks again.